# MapAt a function at specific positions

Tags: equation-solving, map

I'm trying to solve for $p3$ in  `3p3-5 = p1 + p2` at positions where `p1*p2 == 0`:

```
deltap = 10^(-2)

tabletry = Table[p1*p2, {p1, 0, 2}, {p2, 0, 2}]  // MatrixForm

tabletest = Table[{If[p1*p2 == 0, True, False  ]}, {p1, 0, 2}, {p2, 0, 2}] // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 \\
 0 & 2 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 {(True)}\ & (True) & (True) \\
 \ (True) & (False) & (False) \\
 \ (True) & (False) & (False) \\
\end{array}
\right) $$

```
(Array[# #2 /. {(0) -> Style[Solve[3 p3 - 5 == # + #2, p3][[1, 1, -1]], Red], _ :> 
   0} &, {3, 3}, 0]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

EDIT

Now I'm trying to up the level of code, trying to **evaluate** the difference in `p3` following at `true` entries. Full code:

```
deltap = 10^-2;

tabletry = (Table[p1*p2, {p1, 0, 2}, {p2, 0, 2}] ) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
tst = ( Map[{# ==  0 } &, tabletry, {-1}] ) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
eqn1 = 1/p3 - 5p3 = p1 + p2 

eqn2 = 1/p3 - 5p3 + deltap = p1 + p2

diff = p3 /. FindRoot[eqn2, {p3,1}] - p3 /. FindRoot[eqn1,{p3,1}]

(Array[# #2 /. {(0) -> Style[Evaluate[diff[#, #2]][[1, 1, -1]], Red], _ :> 
       0} &, {3, 3}, 0]) // MatrixForm
```

Comment: `Solve[p3 == p1 + p2 &&  And @@ ((# == 0 || # == 1 || # == 2) & /@ {p1, p2}) &&  p1*p2 == 0, {p1, p2, p3}]`

Comment: @belisarius I'm trying to solve for p3 at each entry, as p1 and p2 run from 0 to 2. So the output should be a 3x3 matrix of p3 values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your second question, you could use

```
(tabletry = Table[p1*p2, {p1, 0, 2}, {p2, 0, 2}]) // MatrixForm;
(* or  (tabletry = Array[# #2 &, {3, 3}, 0]) // MatrixForm; *)
(tst = Map[{# == 0} &, tabletry, {-1}]) // MatrixForm
```

or

```
(tst2 = Array[# #2 /. {0 -> {True}, _ -> {False}} &, {3, 3}, 0]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Note the parantheses wrapping the definitions -- without those you would be setting the lhs to `MatrixForm[rhs]`

For the first part, assuming you want to leave the non-zero entries untouched, you could use

```
(mybestwildguessaboutexpectedoutput = 
   Array[# #2 /. (0) -> Style[Solve[3 p3 - 5 == # + #2, p3][[1, 1, -1]], 
                              Red, Bold] &, {3, 3}, 0]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

You could also use

```
MapIndexed[# /. (0) -> Solve[3 p3 - 5 == Plus @@ (#2 - 1), p3][[1, 1, -1]] &, tabletry, {2}]
```

Comment: That looks very good. Is there a way to set the non-relevant entries all to a number, say 0 or 1?

Comment: @user44840, you can use `Array[# #2 /. {(0) -> Solve[3 p3 - 5 == # + #2, p3][[1, 1, -1]], _ :> zz} &, {3, 3}, 0]` and use the number of your choice for `zz`.

Comment: @kguler very nice and helped me understand aims of question...like your long variable name:)

Comment: your post has been nothing short of brilliant so far. However, I think it is limited to simple equations that allow you to explicitly write `3 p3 - 5 == # + #2` then what about more complex equations that depend on p1 and p2 implicitly?

Comment: @user44840, thank you for the kind words. I _think_ it should work for any equation involving three variable `p1,p2,p3`. If, for example, you have `eq = foo[p1,p2,p3]==bar[p1,p2,p3]` in place of `3 p3 -5 == p1 +p2` you can use `eq /. {p1 ->#, p2->#2}`.

Comment: I have edited the code, it doesn't seem to work..

Comment: @user44840, (1) you need `==` (not `=)` on the rhs of `eqn1 and eqn2`, (2) you should provide the value for `deltap` (3) not clear how parse the rhs of `diff` -- paranthesizing would help..

Comment: @kguler Oh yes, I missed that out. I'm trying to observe how the solution for p3 changes with small 'additions' to the equations. It still doesn't seem to work

Comment: @user44840, here is a suggestion for the issues in the update in your post: (1) `ClearAll[eqn1, eqn2, diff];
deltap = .5; eqn1[p1_?NumericQ, p2_?NumericQ, p3_] := 1/p3 - 5 p3 == p1 + p2;
eqn2[p1_?NumericQ, p2_?NumericQ, p3_] := 
 1/p3 - 5 p3 + deltap == p1 + p2;
diff[p1_?NumericQ, 
  p2_?NumericQ] := (p3 /. FindRoot[eqn2[p1, p2, p3], {p3, 1}]) - (p3 /. FindRoot[eqn1[p1, p2, p3], {p3, 1}])`

Comment: ... then (2) use `(Array[# #2 /. {(0) -> Quiet@Style[Evaluate[diff[#, #2]], Red], _ :> 0} &, {3, 3}, 0])` (without `Quiet` you would get a number of error messages.)

Answer (score 2):

Your p3 definitions seem different. The following uses 3p3 -5=p1+p2.

```
set = Tuples[Range[0, 2], 2];
set /. {x_, y_} :> (x + y + 5)/3. /; x y == 0
```

yields:

```
{1.66667, 2., 2.33333, 2., {1, 1}, {1, 2}, 2.33333, {2, 1}, {2, 2}}
```

or if you wish to couple results and {p1,p2}:

```
set /. {{x_, y_} :> 
   Rule[{x, y}, (x + y + 5)/3.] /; x y == 0, {x_, y_} :> 
   Sequence[] /; x y != 0}
```

yields:

```
{{0, 0} -> 1.66667, {0, 1} -> 2., {0, 2} -> 2.33333, {1, 0} -> 
  2., {2, 0} -> 2.33333}
```

Comment: you used (x + y + 5)/3 knowing the expression for p3, but I'm looking for a more general way to solve it. Also, I need to use the table of values tabletry, instead of using " set = Tuples[Range[0, 2], 2]; "

Answer (score 1):

I post this as another answer (using again $ 3p3=p1+p2-5$) if the matrices are the main aim:

```
sa0 = SparseArray[{i_, j_} :> (i - 1) (j - 1), {3, 3}] // MatrixForm;
sa = SparseArray[{{i_, 
        j_} /; ((i - 1) (j - 1) != 0) :> (i - 1) (j - 1), {i_, 
        j_} /; ((i - 1) ( j - 1) == 0) :> (i + j + 5)/3.}, {3, 3}] // 
   MatrixForm;
Row[{sa0, "\[RightArrow]", saf}]
```

[image]

UPDATE

If you are just dealing with linear combinations, and your equations can be represented as $r p3 = m p1+ n p2+s$ then (borrowing from kguler and comments re desired output):

```
h[0, {a_, b_}, func_, v_] := 
 Style[v /. First@Solve[func, v], Bold, Red]
h[x_?(# != 0 &), __] := "x"
```

then you can use `MapIndexed`:

Here demonstrated using random quadruplet of integers:

```
Column[Function[{u, v, w, t}, 
   u p3 == {p1, p2}.{v, w} + 
      t -> (MapIndexed[h[#1, #2, u p3 == #2.{v, w} + t, p3] &, 
       SparseArray[{i_, j_} :> (i - 1) (j - 1), {3, 3}], {2}] // 
      MatrixForm)] @@@ RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {10, 4}], Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to incorporate FindRoot or Solve into the solution, so it would work for more complex equations. In these equations, we won't know  p3=(p1 + p2 + 5)/3

Comment: It should incorporate something like ´ FindRoot[eqn, {p3,initial}] ´